# how to display the username after login instead of login and register form

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, webmatrix-2

i have created a login page using ASP classic.

The problem is that after the login it redirect to the index page with the same login and register button  instead of display the username or email id?

Thanks in advance...

Here is the code(VBScript).

```
<%
email = ""
password = ""
ErrorMessage = ""

if request.form <> "" then
email = Request.Form("email")
 password = Request.Form("password")

 if email = "" or password = "" then
 ErrorMessage = "You must specify a username and password."
 else
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
 conn.Open("F:\main\main\App_Data\Users.mdb")
 set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * FROM Login WHERE Email = '" & email & "'", conn
 response.write("email")

if rs.EOF = false then 

 if rs.fields("Password") = password then
  Response.Redirect("indexs.asp")

end if
 end if 
ErrorMessage = "Login failed"
end if 
end if

if ErrorMessage <> "" then
response.write("<p>" & ErrorMessage & "</p>") 
 response.write("<p>Please correct the errors and try again.</p>") 

end if
%>
```

Comment: _" after the login it redirect to the index page with the same login and register button instead of display the username or email id"_ - What does that mean???

Comment: Your question is not clear.. are you posting data from index.asp page ?

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable before you redirect to index.asp eg

```
Session("username") = rs("username")
```

You can then use the session variable in a conditional statement on your index page eg

```
If session("username") = "" Then

 'your login form goes here

else

response.write "Welcome "+ session("username")

End If
```